# laravel 5 throws token error on facebook canvas

Tags: laravel-5, facebook-access-token, facebook-canvas

I try to build a facebook canvas app using laravel 5. I use a custom middleware class to disable crsf for specific routes. can be found [here](http://www.camroncade.com/disable-csrf-for-specific-routes-laravel-5/). I ended up with another error.

> Class 'App\Http\Middleware\TokenMismatchException' not found

This is my middlewareclass:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

class VerifyCsrfMiddleware extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
    if ($this->isReading($request) || $this->excludedRoutes($request) || $this->tokensMatch($request))
      {
        return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
      }

      throw new TokenMismatchException;
}

    /**
     * Ignore CSRF on these routes.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return bool
     */
    private function excludedRoutes($request)
    {
        $routes = [
          'app/canvas'
          // ... insert all your canvas endpoints here
        ];

        foreach($routes as $route){
            if ($request->is($route)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```